# All websites report 0 visits for July/August apart from 1

Tags: google-analytics

We have about 12 websites, all except 1 of them reported 0 visits for July and August in Google Analytics.

If I check with Chrome Tag Assistant, the GA tag is present for each of them.

I have been checking the "Unfiltered Master" view of each property, meaning our own company's visits should at least be recorded.

Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a "All Users - Clean" customised segment selected.

Changing back to the "All Users" segment showed more than 0 visitors.